# show range in a log scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to include the range of possible values for `y_val` where the upper and lower bands are available. I tried using `geom_errorbar` which works for the continuous scale but not in log scale. How can I fix this?

```
x_val <- c(2, 3, 6, 12, 24)
y_val<-c(1,3,15,25,30) 
y_upper<- c(1.2,3.2, 16, 28,40)
y_lower <-c(0.8,2.9, 12, 22,25)

df <- data.frame(x_val=x_val,y_val=y_val,y_upper=y_upper,
                 y_lower=y_lower)

ggplot(data=df,aes(x=x_val,y=y_val))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point()+
  geom_errorbar(ymin = y_lower, ymax = y_upper)+
  scale_y_log10()+
  scale_x_log10()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A trick could be to use `geom_segment` with `arrow` settings produced by a call to `arrow()`.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data=df,aes(x=x_val,y=y_val))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point()+
  geom_segment(aes(xend = x_val, y = y_lower, yend = y_upper),
               arrow = arrow(angle = 90, ends = "both")) +
  scale_y_log10()+
  scale_x_log10()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65525087/errorbars-in-a-log-scale-plot) answer, you need `coord_trans(y = "log10")` rather than `scale_y_log10()`

```r
library(ggplot2)

x_val <- c(2, 3, 6, 12, 24)
y_val<-c(1,3,15,25,30) 
y_upper<- c(1.2,3.2, 16, 28,40)
y_lower <-c(0.8,2.9, 12, 22,25)

df <- data.frame(x_val=x_val,
                 y_val=y_val,
                 y_upper=y_upper,
                 y_lower=y_lower)

ggplot(data=df,aes(x=x_val,y=y_val))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point()+
  geom_errorbar(ymin = y_lower, ymax = y_upper)+
  coord_trans(y="log10", x = "log10", ylim = range(c(y_upper, y_lower)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>