# How to ggplot geom_errorbar when using log scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to produce a summary line plot with SD error bars on both a linear and logarithmic y axis.
I can do this easily enough on the linear scale, but how does one account for the log scale, when generating valid SD error bars?
Do I need to manually calculate a geometric SD perhaps? Not sure how to achieve this.

Dummy data:

```
library(dplyr)
dat <- structure(list(time = c(0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 
                             5, 5.5, 6, 6.5, 7, 7.5, 8, 8.5, 9, 9.5, 10, 10.5, 11, 11.5, 12, 
                             0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5, 5.5, 6, 6.5, 7, 7.5, 
                             8, 8.5, 9, 9.5, 10, 10.5, 11, 11.5, 12, 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 
                             3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5, 5.5, 6, 6.5, 7, 7.5, 8, 8.5, 9, 9.5, 10, 10.5, 
                             11, 11.5, 12, 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5, 5.5, 
                             6, 6.5, 7, 7.5, 8, 8.5, 9, 9.5, 10, 10.5, 11, 11.5, 12, 0, 0.5, 
                             1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5, 5.5, 6, 6.5, 7, 7.5, 8, 8.5, 
                             9, 9.5, 10, 10.5, 11, 11.5, 12, 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 
                             4, 4.5, 5, 5.5, 6, 6.5, 7, 7.5, 8, 8.5, 9, 9.5, 10, 10.5, 11, 
                             11.5, 12), dv = c(0, 0.18432616, 0.88526902, 1.2296906, 1.28501176, 
                                               1.2139172, 1.09455226, 0.96353803, 0.83722931, 0.72220134, 0.62040715, 
                                               0.53169995, 0.45505514, 0.38915199, 0.33264156, 0.2842622, 0.24288196, 
                                               0.20750707, 0.1772753, 0.15144348, 0.12937353, 0.11051874, 0.09441129, 
                                               0.08065113, 0.06889633, 0, 0.18646195, 0.9048901, 1.28471715, 
                                               1.37742791, 1.33879388, 1.24474175, 1.13178462, 1.01703554, 0.90810807, 
                                               0.80800831, 0.71754717, 0.63652547, 0.56431222, 0.50012324, 0.44315229, 
                                               0.39262987, 0.34784693, 0.30816176, 0.27299918, 0.24184632, 0.21424719, 
                                               0.18979702, 0.16813683, 0.14894842, 0, 0.18294322, 0.87292448, 
                                               1.19567138, 1.22915435, 1.14027058, 1.00823429, 0.8693954, 0.73934779, 
                                               0.62380257, 0.52390843, 0.43883218, 0.36699104, 0.30662467, 0.25604644, 
                                               0.21374115, 0.1783911, 0.14887033, 0.12422626, 0.10365757, 0.08649245, 
                                               0.07216874, 0.06021662, 0.05024367, 0.0419223, 0, 0.18697047, 
                                               0.90966337, 1.29828203, 1.40059765, 1.37067756, 1.2838258, 1.17643544, 
                                               1.06571995, 0.95947803, 0.86092175, 0.77106034, 0.68987364, 0.61688687, 
                                               0.55144953, 0.49286823, 0.44046784, 0.39361759, 0.35174019, 0.31431303, 
                                               0.28086579, 0.25097654, 0.22426743, 0.20040041, 0.17907321, 0, 
                                               0.18531778, 0.89429381, 1.25485411, 1.32695875, 1.27013735, 1.16158786, 
                                               1.03796132, 0.91603064, 0.80290267, 0.7010534, 0.61080177, 0.53151718, 
                                               0.46220211, 0.40176719, 0.34915557, 0.30339446, 0.26361157, 0.22903568, 
                                               0.19899009, 0.17288363, 0.15020104, 0.13049386, 0.11337208, 0.09849667, 
                                               0, 0.18383905, 0.88088906, 1.21756741, 1.26499344, 1.18736204, 
                                               1.0632291, 0.92915041, 0.80123546, 0.68577026, 0.58443313, 0.49683915, 
                                               0.42176711, 0.35773895, 0.30328282, 0.25704292, 0.21781669, 0.18455866, 
                                               0.15636983, 0.13248206, 0.11224132, 0.09509189, 0.0805622, 0.06825233, 
                                               0.05782327)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -150L))

# Summarise
dat_summarised <- dat |> 
  group_by(time) |> 
  summarise(mean = mean(dv, na.rm = T), 
            sd = sd(dv, na.rm = T))

# Plot linear (this works)
dat_summarised |> 
    ggplot(aes(x = time, y = mean)) +
    geom_point(size = 3) +
    geom_line(linewidth = 0.8) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = mean + sd, ymin = mean - sd), width = 0.1) +
    theme_classic(base_size = 20)

# Plot log (this doesn't work)
dat_summarised |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = mean)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  geom_line(linewidth = 0.8) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = mean + sd, ymin = mean - sd), width = 0.1) +
  scale_y_log10() +
  theme_classic(base_size = 20)
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot about the zeros. But that wasn't my main concern. My main concern was that the SD was calculated on the linear, not log scale. Maybe I am just confusing myself, as it's only the plot scale that's changing right, not the actual values. If that's the case, then nothing needs to really change from the original code.

Comment: I also came across this response which didn't clarify things for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65525087/errorbars-in-a-log-scale-plot

Comment: The log transformation is monotone. In my answer the transformation `log(dv + 1L)` is done previous to the utilisation of `geom_errorbar()`, such that this function uses the transformed values of `sd` and `mean`. You should be concerned about the zero values.

Answer (score 0):

What about transforming the `mean` and `sd` variable in a preceding step?

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(ggplot2)
})

dat |> 
  summarise(mean = mean(log(dv + 1L), na.rm = TRUE), 
            sd = sd(log(dv + 1L), na.rm = TRUE), 
            .by = time) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = mean)) +
  geom_point(size = 3L) +
  geom_line(linewidth = .8) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = mean + sd, ymin = mean - sd), width = .1) +
  # scale_y_log10() +
  theme_classic(base_size = 20L)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Your log transformation causes problems due to some zero values: `log(0)` is `-Inf`. You cold try `mean(log(dv + 1L), na.rm = TRUE)` and
`sd = sd(log(dv + 1L), na.rm = TRUE)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem aren't the errorbars, but a 0 in your means. 0 can't be converted to a position in a logarithmic plot, because it would be a -Inf.

If you remove your first datapoint, or replace it with a small value it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could eliminate zeros and negatives in a logarithm using the function `log(x - min(x) - 1)` in `scale_y_continuous` like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

dat_summarised |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = mean)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  geom_line(linewidth = 0.8) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = mean + sd, ymin = mean - sd), width = 0.1) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = \(x) log(x - (min(x) - 1))) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 20)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>